# Visual Studio 2012 automatically creates virtual directory in IIS 7 on start

Tags: visual-studio-2012, iis-7

I have a web project hosted in another web project on IIS 7.

My Settings are like that:

*Project Properties -> Web*

**Use Local Web Server** [checked]

**Use IIS Express** [unchecked]

**Project Url**: localhost/BIG_PROJECT/My_small_project

*Project Propertirs -> Build*

Output Path: **..\bin**

There is a virtual directory for BIG_PROJECT. It's Ok.

But every time I open My_small_project in Visual Studio 2012, it automatically creates virtual directory for My_small_project.

Is there any setting for this behaviour to turn off?